# Azure Analysis Services Programatically Vertical Scale up or down - change service tier

Tags: scaling, azure-analysis-services

We process and refresh our AAS models in ADFv2 using API calls.

We want to be able vertically scale up (change the tier) just before we refresh the model and then scale back down once it's done.

I can't find an API call to do this or any kind of command to execute within a pipeline in ADF.

It's simple for Azure SQL database

```
ALTER DATABASE <db_name> MODIFY (SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'service-tier')
```

For reasons out of my control, using runbooks is not an option.

There must be alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the REST API

```
Set-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $AnalysisServerName -Sku "S1"
```

for altering the tier.

Note: you cannot change between basic to standard via manual or API approach.
You can only alter around within the same scope of tier like S1,S2.S4 etc

You can leverage ADF web activity to do the same